# Is there a more lightweight alternative to array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to create an array with 3 billion boolean variables. My memory is only 4GB, therefore I need this array to be very tight (at most one byte per variable). Theoretically this should be possible. But I found that Ruby uses way too much space for one boolean variable in an array.

```
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(Array.new(100, false))   #=> 840
```

That's more than 8 bytes per variable. I would like to know if there's a more lightweight implementation of C-arrays in Ruby.

Apart from a small profile, I also need each boolean this array to be fast accessible, because I need to flip them as fast as possible on demand.

Comment: Use bitmaps. Have one string and just flip single bits of it. No array overhead, 8 values per byte. Cool, huh? :)

Comment: Why won't you just store your bits in integers?

Comment: [`NArray.byte`](https://masa16.github.io/narray/)

Comment: @cremno: It seems that NArray.byte doesn't support arrays longer than 2^31.

Comment: @cremno `a = NArray.byte(3000000000)  #> RangeError: integer 3000000000 too big to convert to 'int'`

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Thank you for your comments. I agree that bit-arrays/bitmaps are possible ways to get this done, but will there be a big speed compromise comparing to direct memory access? Besides, is there a good implementation that you recommend or do I have to write the operation logic myself?

Comment: @trVoldemort, why you ask about small size? Ruby isn't fast and small as plain C. Ruby pays speed and size for candy functions and oop. Just... go to C if you want optimizations

Comment: Just curious: why do you need to hold three billion bits in an array (i.e., in memory)? Also: memory is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby isn't a well performing language, especially in memory use.  As other said, you should put your booleans in numbers.  You'll lose a lot of memory due to ruby's 'objetification'.  If it is a bad scenario to you, you may store into strings of a large length and store the strings in a array, losing less memory.

http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/

You also can implement your own gem in C++, that can naturally use bits and doubles, losing less memory.  And array of doubles means 64 booleans in each position, more than sufficient to your application.

Extremely large objects are always a problem and will require you to implement a lot to make easier to work with your large collection of objects.  Surely you'll have to at least implement some kind of method to acess some position in an array of objects that store more than one boolean, and other to flip them.

Answer (score 0):

The following class may not be exactly what you're looking for.  It will store 1's or 0's into an array using bits and shifting.  Entries default to 0. If you need three states for each entry, 0, 1, or nil, then you'd need to change it to use two bits for each entry, rather than one.

```
class BitArray < Array
  BITS_PER_WORD = 0.size * 8
  MASK = eval("0x#{'FF' * (BITS_PER_WORD/8)}") - 1

  def []=(n, value_0_or_1)
    word = word_at(n / BITS_PER_WORD) || 0
    word &= MASK << n % BITS_PER_WORD
    super(n / BITS_PER_WORD, value_0_or_1 << (n % BITS_PER_WORD) | word)
  end
  def [](n)
    return 0 if word_at(n / BITS_PER_WORD).nil?
    (super(n / BITS_PER_WORD) >> (n % BITS_PER_WORD)) & 1
  end

  def word_at(n)
    Array.instance_method('[]').bind(self).call(n)
  end
end
```